# Can a controller on a twig template be extended in an other twig template?

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

I'm making a web site with Symfony and I'm having some problems.
Let's say I have three templates : base.html.twig, index.html.twig and menu.html.twig.

The **base** template can be used for all my pages, my **index** template extends the **base** template and also my **menu** template.

I have a controller to render my index.html.twig with the route "/projectmanager/dashboard".

I want to have a controller for my **menu** template because I must display data from a database, but I don't succeed from doing it.

Do you have an idea how to do it ?

I'm new to Stackoverflow and a beginner with Symfony, I just study it.
If you need more information about my code, just ask it.

Thanks for the support !

Comment: "my index template extends the base template and also my menu template": that's impossible, you can only extend a single template. You can `include` the menu template in your index template, though.

Comment: Upsi dupsi, you're right ! Indeed my menu template was included to my index template ! I just made a keyboard typos.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem by using an twig instruction in my index.html.twig template which is :

{{ render(controller('App\Controller\Menu\menuController')) }}

This twig instruction calls the controller of my menu.

I figure it out on a french forum where someone share me this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html).